# How to solve this integral inquality?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-transform

Let $ f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e ^{-x^2/2} $.
In a paper the author claims that $ \int_{\mathbb{R}} |w| f(w) dw \leq \left(  \int_{\mathbb{R}} |w|^2 f(w) dw  \right)^{1/2} $.
I don't see a good argument for the step. I would use Cauchy-Schwarz inquality (with $ L^2 $- norm), Minkowsky inquality or Hölder inquality but they don't seem to fit.

Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f(x)$ is the probability density function of a normal distribution, it reduces to
$$
\mathbb{E}\lvert Z\rvert\leq[\mathbb{E}\lvert Z\rvert^2]^{1/2}
$$
which is immediate from Cauchy-Schwarz.